# How can i do web scapping in powershell 2.0

Tags: html, powershell, web-scraping, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I tried below solution to basically retrieve table info from an url, or just html content form the url, but its not working in Powershell 2.0 as I can run this same script in powershell 5.0 please help me find some solution

```
$url= "https:\\somewebsite"
$WebRequest = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$html = $WebRequest.DownloadString($url)
```

Comment: Really? `windows-server-2008-r2` and `powershell-2.0`? ... why?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: helpless situation  (╥_╥)

Comment: Please tell us what "not working" means - are you getting errors? If so, please post the error message in full. Unexpected HTML output? Tell us what you were expecting as content and what you unexpectedly got instead

Comment: DownloadString : Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:35
+ $html = $WebRequest.DownloadString <<<< ($url)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell 2.0 does not have `-UseDefaultCredentials`.

Change it to use `.Credentials` instead:

```
$url = "https://somewebsite"
$WebRequest = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebRequest.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$html = $WebRequest.DownloadString($url)
```